# 3 Phase electrical Machine in Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I want to draw a symbol for a three phase AC Machine with three connections, similar to what Plecs does:

[image]

I assume I could do that by hand, is there a quicker option with Circuitikz?

Comment: There is no such symbol in `circuitikz`, but there is a new chapter in the manual on how to add symbols... But for one shot use, I would draw it "by hand".

Answer (score 4):

To get you started, look at this: I am adding border anchors on the circle and an anchor to the `elmech` shape (will commit similar changes in the future version, these anchors are useful). (Changes are between `%%%`, the code is taken from `pgfcirctripoles.tex`).

Changing the shape to be similar to your drawing should be easy (but if you do it, please rename it).

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
% electromechanical device (motor/generator)
\pgfdeclareshape{elmech}
{
    \savedanchor\northwest{
        \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/elmech/height}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
        \pgf@x=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/elmech/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{center}{
        \pgfpointorigin
    }
    \anchor{text}{
        \pgfpointorigin
        \advance \pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \advance \pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
    }
    \anchor{left}{%
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{right}{%
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{top}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{pathstart}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{pathend}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{bottom}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{center}{
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{east}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{west}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{south}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{north}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{south west}{ \northwest \pgf@y=-\pgf@y }
    \anchor{north east}{ \northwest \pgf@x=-\pgf@x }
    \anchor{north west}{ \northwest }
    \anchor{south east}{ \northwest \pgf@x=-\pgf@x \pgf@y=-\pgf@y }
    %%%% added for here
    \anchorborder{%
        \@tempdima=\pgf@x\@tempdimb=\pgf@y
        \northwest\pgf@circ@res@other=-\pgf@x
        \pgfpointborderellipse{\pgfqpoint{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@other}}
    }
    \anchor{block down right}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=-0.85\pgf@y % we should calculate this better, let's go for now
        \pgf@x=-0.5\pgf@x
    }
    %%%%
    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfsetcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/color}}
        \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{tripoles/elmech/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgf@circ@res@up=\ctikzvalof{tripoles/elmech/height}\pgf@circ@Rlen
        \pgfscope
            \pgfstartlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
            \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
            \pgfscope % clip the bar: whole size minus the circle
                \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-.5\pgf@circ@res@step}{-.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@step}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}} {0.5\pgf@circ@res@step}
                \pgfseteorule
                \pgfusepath{clip}
                \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{-.25\pgf@circ@res@step}{-.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfsetfillcolor{black}
                \pgfusepath{fill, draw}
            \endpgfscope
            \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}} {0.5\pgf@circ@res@step}
            \ifx\tikz@fillcolor\pgfutil@empty
                \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
            \else
                \pgfsetfillcolor{\tikz@fillcolor}
            \fi
            \pgfusepath{draw, fill}
        \endpgfscope
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    ]
    \node [elmech](M){ac};
    \draw (M.180) -- ++(-.3,0) coordinate(a);
    \draw (M.150) -- (M.150 -| a);
    \draw (M.210) -- (M.210 -| a);
    % \node [circle, fill=red, inner sep=.2pt] at (M.block down right){};
    \draw (M.block down right) -- ++(0.3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pushed; https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/259

Answer (score 1):

I addition to Rmanos approach heres is my version. There are now anchors on it, but it might be useful nevertheless.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}           %% Grafikeinbindung
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (-5, 0) circle (1cm);
        \node [draw, thick, shape=rectangle, minimum width=0.4cm, minimum height=1.2cm, anchor=center] at (-5,0) {};
        \draw (-5.2, 0.4) to (-4.8, 0.4);
        \draw (-5, 0) ++(210:1cm) -- ++ (-0.2, -0.5) -- ++ (0, -0.5) -- ++ (2, 0); 
        \begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1]
            \draw (5, 0) ++(210:1cm) -- ++ (-0.2, -0.5) -- ++ (0, -0.5) -- ++ (2, 0); 
        \end{scope}
        \node[color=black, below] at (-5,-1.5) {PMSM};
    \end{circuitikz}
    %electrical machine


\end{document}
```

[image]